# how to reference a nested model in another model, mongoose 5.0

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

How to reference a nested model in another model. For example, having this shema, where I want to reference `subcategories` in `User` schema:

```
var UserSchema = Schema({
    publications: [{
    name:String,
    categories: [{
     type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
     refPath: 'Category.subcategories._id'
    }]
   }]
});
```

The category contains `subcategories` as well, and defined as follows:

```
var CategorySchema = Schema({
    name: String,
    subcategories: [{
        name: String
    }]
});
```

I am trying to reference `subcategories` of `CategorySchema`.

Answer (score 1):

Referencing `Category` in `User` schema will do the job, because `subcategories` is included in `Category`. This is how you need to do:

First, define a shema file for your `Category` model containing this code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CategorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    subcategories: [{
        name: String
    }]
});

const Category = mongoose.model('Category', 'CategorySchema', 'Category');
module.exports = { Category };
```

Second, define a schema file for your `User` model containing this code:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Category = mongoose.model('Category');

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    publications: [{
      name:String,
      Category: Category.schema
    }]
});

const User= mongoose.model('User', 'UserSchema', 'User');
module.exports = { User };
```